# how do i open a jpg image inside a tkinter window in python 3.6?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to load an image in the tkinter window but it only shows errors like: "no such file or directory", is this for another version of python? If so what could i use for python 3.6?

```
from tkinter import *

# pip install pillow
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
 load = Image.open("hello.jpg")
  render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

   img = Label(self, image=render)
   img.image = render
   img.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: Where are you running this code from, and where is the image? Furthermore, what is the file that is listed in the error?

Comment: The message suggests that the file is not where you think it is, I would suggest to look at where this script is run from, what the script views as it's working directory and where the file is located.

Comment: i'm running this on a chrome os does that change the result?

Comment: im running the code on repl.it

Comment: "no such file or directory" means literally that - you're giving the code a path to a file that doesn't exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check which directory the `hello.jpg` file is in. The error you're getting means that it couldn't find that file where it was looking. It currently is looking in the same folder that the python file is in

---

## Solution

> **Make sure that the directory which this python script is in also has the image**

*Your file should look something like this*:

**You should have some folder that this python file is in, and in that same folder that the python file is in you should have the TKinter images**

On repl.it you should press this button:

[image: Picture of repl.it]

Then add the hello.jpg file

You also need to change your code to remove the random indents as well as adding root = Tk() to "activate" TkInter

Your new code should look like this:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# pip install pillow
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
load = Image.open("hello.jpg")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

img = Label(self, image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0, y=0)
```

Comment: i don't have any python folder though, i'm running python in an webside (repl.it) on a chrome os so the image would automaticly be in google drive.

Comment: @MartinTerner-7E-Alle Okay, on the website repl.it add the image, I'll add some screenshots now.

Comment: @MartinTerner-7E-Alle Okay, checkout the new answer

Comment: @MartinTerner-7E-Alle You also need to remove random indents and add `root = Tk()`

Comment: @MartinTerner-7E-Alle Once you add all of that there is a chance that it might not work because TkInter was designed for a desktop, running it on the web might not work

Comment: it just says: some files may fail to load in the browser   no matter what file i pick

Comment: @BryanOakley True but that case is pretty rare and his problem is most likely not in running in a different directory than where the project is, __especially__ because he is running this on repl.it

Comment: i couldn't figure it out, i don't think it can load images. At least not from chrome os.